# Equation of a curve with a local minimum fixed at $x=a$ when we rotate the curve about the origin.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

> We have a strangely curved plank. If we place a round weighted object on it, it will rest itself at one point of it, when we incline the plank slowly, the object will gradually move towards a resting point of the plank, but it will not move horizontally, only vertically. Find the equation of the lever.

[image]

I find this to be quite a beautiful problem.

I know we have to find $f(x)$ so that $f'(a) = 0$ is a local minimum and if we rotate it an angle $\theta$ about the origin, then $f'_{\theta}(a) = 0$.

Writing the equation in polar form makes it easier to handle rotation, but then I don't know a way to find the minimum, and if I write it the normal way I don't know a way to rotate it.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. I cannot visualize the description.

Comment: The second line after the grey box explains the problem at hand

Comment: I also don't understand the problem. Is the plank a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$, or a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$? When you write $f(x)$, is $x \in \mathbb{R}$? What do you mean by $f_\theta$?

Comment: @PhillipAndreae $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. $f_\theta$ is $f$ rotated an angle of $\theta$ about $(0,0)$. I'll add a picture to the question to ilustrate it.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Nice picture. Interesting problem!

Comment: Yeah, it was a bit hard to explain. I've read that the normal points of the curve must be tangent to a circumference, but I don't know how they got there or how to proceed from there.